# Can I debug gwt component directly in intellij IDEA

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, gwt

I am currently working with IntelliJ IDEA and I try to debug gwt components directly in the IDE. 
I know I can use Chrome DevTools to debug, but it's always a pain, when the variables names change and it takes quite a long time to debug.

I thing I have seen somewhere the fact that you can directly debug your component in IntelliJ but I am not sure where I have seen that.

I am in superdevmode but when I add a breakpoint in my java class in IntelliJ it does not get validated and does not stop in IntelliJ. It only works in Chrome.

Here is my gwt configuration

[image: GWT CONFIG]

Thanks a lot.

Thoma

Comment: What is GWT version? Make sure you have [GWT facet](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gwt-facet-page.html) defined for the module with path to GWT installation. Check [Sample GWT application](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gwt-sample-application-overview.html) which IDE creates to see the application structure, the IDE configuration and try to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

It sure does work from within IntelliJ.

One thing I noted in your screenshot : Set a checkbox with "with JavaScript debugger".

That is the only thing I see different with my setup, in which breakpoints work in IntelliJ, and in the browser.

Comment: Does not work for me :( All I have is the javascript console log in the debugger console

Comment: According to the screenshot I assume you do, but you are using the paid version of IntelliJ ?